# Django empty get variables

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi I have an ajax call which is hooked up with a small view:

```
def get_spans(snow_load, wind_speed, module_length):
    spans = Spans.objects.values_list('span').filter(
        snow=snow_load,
        wind=wind_speed,
        module_length__gte=module_length,
    ).order_by('span')
    try:
        max_span = max(spans)
    except ValueError:
        max_span = 0
    return max_span

def GetSpans(request):
    # get variables from ajax request
    snow_load = request.GET.get('snow_load', None)
    wind_speed = request.GET.get('wind_speed', None)
    module_length = request.GET.get('module_length', None)
    # call get_spans()
    max_span = get_spans(snow_load, wind_speed, module_length)
    # json encode it
    max_span = simplejson.dumps(max_span, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(
        max_span,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
```

The problem is that any of these get variables could be `''` or decimals. My question is what is the best way to handle these? If the variables are `''` I get `invalid literal for int() with base 10:` errors. Should I replace all empty strings with `None` for example? Should I cast all values to `float`?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters in django can be chained, so you can do this:

```
spans = Spans.objects.values_list('span')
if snow_load:
   spans.filter(snow=snow_load)
if wind_speed:
    spans.filter(wind=wind_speed)
if module_length:
    spans.filter(module_length__gte=module_length)

return max(spans.order_by('span'))
```

Comment: I think this is along the lines of what I need. If the value of any variable is '' or None I just want to discount it from the filter and return a bigger query set. Is this the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Its _one_ way which is legible and easy to understand (which is part of being pythonic). The `if` check will fail on "falsey" values (like `''`) and obviously `None`.

Comment: Does this make one or three calls to the db?

Comment: It will still make one db call.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `get_spans` you can exclude the empty or None fields:

```
def get_spans(*args, **kwargs):
   my_dict = {}
   for key in kwargs:
      if kwargs[key]:
         my_dict[key] = kwargs[key]
    spans = Spans.objects.values_list('span') \
                         .filter(**my_dict) \
                         .order_by('span')
    #rest of code
```

Call your `get_spans` function as:

```
get_spans(snow=snow_load, wind=wind_speed, module_length__gte=module_length)
```

**More Elegant**

`Requires python2.7+`

```
def get_spans(*args, **kwargs):
    my_dict = {key:val for (key, val) in kwargs.iteritems() if val}
    spans = Spans.objects.values_list('span') \
                         .filter(**my_dict) \
                         .order_by('span')
    #rest of code
```

Comment: Definitely getting there. This only filters on the fields I have values for. That is correct isn't it?

Comment: obviously it will exclude those fields which are empty or None.

Comment: Any comments on which is the better answer of the ones provided here?

Comment: This is the good solution in my point of view, chained filters are also an option, but if you have more filters to check for then it will take lots of lines to write.

Comment: I understand. However, I think I am going with the first answer due to chronology and legibility (for future django devs). I do appreciate the elegance of your answer though @Aamir.